# Enter key on EditText hitting onKey twice

Tags: android

I've attached an OnKeyListener to an EditText.  I've overrode the onKey handler to capture a KeyEvent.

When a user hits the enter key (either their computer enter key while using the emulator, or the hardware enter key on their phone with a hardware keyboard), the onKey handler gets executed twice.  Both executions have the keyCode 66.

Why is this happening?

I want my screen so when the user hits the enter key, a search is performed.  Because of what is happening, the search is needlessly happening twice.

My method looks like this:

```
   mFilter.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                // perform search
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ahhhh

I think this is happening for key up and key down?

Comment: Probably. Check the `KeyEvent`, not just the code. I've found some issues historically with the HTC keyboard sometimes firing multiple events, though (and sometimes users will just spaz and hit "enter" multiple times anyways), so you may want to keep an instance variable in your listener to just track when the action has been fired so you can prevent an accidental second firing.

Comment: Good idea.  I think, when the search task launches, I'll launch another task with a timer of a few seconds and, until that thread finishes, the user won't be able to hit the enter key again.

Comment: This shouldn't be marked as the answer, please mark one of the below (more useful) answers as the answer (I'd recommend Abdul's). Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction()==0) {
```

Comment: that's for the "key down" and is generated as long as the user is keeping it pressed.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
mFilter.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                // perform search
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10):

you can filter like this :

```
object.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                // do stuff
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

idem when you push the key with KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and the answers above helped me but I am using Xamarin.Android (c#) so it is slightly different syntax.. Here is what worked for me:

```
MyStringTextBox.KeyPressed += OnEnterKeyPressed;

protected void OnEnterKeyPressed(object sender, View.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keycode.Enter && e.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Up)
    {
        DoSomething(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = false;
    }
}
```

This way, the DoSomething() would only be called on hitting Enter Key (Up) only and thus would be fired once. Works and tested on Xamarin.Android

Answer (score 0):

This event is fired by `KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `KeyEvent.ACTION_UP`.
I have done debugging and finally I realize that there is an param called `KeyEvent event` that I never use, then I checked and found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I debugged and what worked for me was that,

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener { view, i, keyEvent ->
            if (i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && enterAsSend && (keyEvent.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP || keyEvent.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)) {
                //Do stuff
                }
                return@OnKeyListener true
            }
            false
        })
```

and checkout your Editext that `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` because the first click of enter key gives us the suggestion from the dictionary.