# How to get message (Toast) ,if any key pressed in keyboard

Tags: android

my application needs a edit text ,when i enter anything in that edit text .it should show a message that for example (Enter pressed ,tab pressed, space pressed )etc.
is there any way to do that. i am doing this

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
 etext =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 etext.setOnKeyListener(this);
 }
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
          Toast.makeText(this, etext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //show tost here
          return true;
     }
    return false;
}*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [setOnKeyListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) as:

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
          Toast.makeText(this, "show message here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //show tost here
          return true;
     }
   return false;
 }
```

**EDIT :** you can find all `keyEvent` here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Comment: imran thanks for reply .its fine with entered text but when i pressing "enter","space" "tab" ,it should show like "enter pressed" or what ever message

Comment: @Himanshusharma : not an issue can u edit your post with latest code.then i will to help more

Comment: @Himanshusharma : try after changing this to YourCurrentActivity.this as Lalit Poptani

Comment: @Himanshusharma : also add else and an toast with if statement then see which toast is showing because it is possible KEYCODE_ENTER happens two times

Comment: i replaced this by MyActivity.this but i am confused that what should i print in message .

Comment: @Himanshusharma : see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513888/enter-key-on-edittext-hitting-onkey-twice

Comment: @thanks imarn this code is working fine for physical keyboard but not for virtual keyboard (only enter ,space are working with this code)

Comment: @Himanshusharma : thanks himanshu,now i'm trying to find how we handle virtual keyboard keys if find any thing then i will update u.or if possible then post a new question about handling keys in Virtual keyboard i think then u will find good answer and make question more clear with relevant code.