# Android webview get software keyboard key pressed

Tags: android, events, webview

I wonder how i can get the key that being pressed in an android webview.

I tryed `dispathKeyEvent`, `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` on `Activity`, `shouldOverrideKeyEvent` on `WebViewClient`
But none of this method trigger the key pressed on the software keyboard.

What im looking to do is to close the software keyboard when the user press the OK button.

Is it any other way that do it throw javascript in the webview. I don't like this way.

Comment: May be this one help you   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682193/hide-or-disable-webview-softkeyboard-go-done-enter-button

Comment: Thanks but it use javascript so not realy what i want here. Looking for a way to do this without JavascriptInterface if it's exist